# fixed point multiplication without 64 bit temporary

Tags: c, optimization, fixed-point

Hi I'm implementing some fixed point math stuff for embedded systems and I'm trying to do the multiplication of two 16.16 fixed point numbers without creating a 64bit temporary. So far here is the code I came up with that generates the least instructions.

```
int multiply(int x, int y){
    int result;
    long long temp = x;
    temp *= y;
    temp >>= 16;
    result = temp;
    return result;
}
```

the problem with this code is that it uses a temporary 64 bit integer which seem to generate bad assembly code. I'm trying to make a system that uses two 32 bit integers instead of a 64 bit one. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you see a 64-bit temporary in the disassembly dump of the output, or just in your head? Just because the source code has a variable of type `long long` does not mean there's actually any "64-bit temporary". On any decent 32-bit arch, a 32x32 multiply automatically generates a 64-bit result, usually separated into two 32-bit registers for your (or the compiler's) convenience. Manipulating these is much more efficient than breaking it down into 4 16x16 multiplies to avoid the "64-bit temporary".

Comment: @R.. yeah I looked into the assembler dump. it uses two halves in the EAX and EDX register but it's implementation is not optimal

Comment: It's surely a lot *less suboptimal* than performing four MULs...

Comment: @R.. the idea is that now that I know how to do it in C I can implement it in hand optimized assembly

Comment: Hope you mean doing the 32x32 -> 64 mul in asm -- that could help, but writing the C efficiently should produce near-identical results. Doing the 4 16x16 muls in asm will be horribly slow.

Comment: most modern x86 compilers will automatically use the upper 32 bits of the result if you specify the optimization level high enough

Comment: ISO C has no extended-precision stuff like shift-between-variables, widening-multiply, or add-with-carry.  Expressing something in C is useful to make sure you understand the algorithm (especially if the widest part is at most 64-bit so you don't have to manually do extended precision), but it's typically not a useful starting point for an efficient asm implementation.  Unless an optimizing compiler does a good job with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of your numbers as each composed of two large "digits."

```
  A.B
x C.D
```

The "base" of the digits is the 2^bit_width, i.e., 2^16, or 65536.

So, the product is

```
D*B       + D*A*65536 + C*B*65536 + C*A*65536*65536
```

However, to get the product shifted right by 16, you need to divide all these terms by 65536, so

```
D*B/65536 + D*A       + C*B        + C*A*65536
```

In C:

```
uint16_t a = x >> 16;
uint16_t b = x & 0xffff;
uint16_t c = y >> 16;
uint16_t d = y & 0xffff;

return ((d * b) >> 16) + (d * a) + (c * b) + ((c * a) << 16);
```

The signed version is a bit more complicated; it is often easiest to perform the arithmetic on the absolute values of `x` and `y` and then fix the sign (unless you overflow, which you can check for rather tediously).

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And this is going to be a lot slower than doing it the way you originally tried.

Comment: Well, the speed depends on the capabilities of the embedded processor (note that I answered the question before the EAX register was mentioned!). On a 16-bit processor, my approach will be slightly faster because a 32x32->64-bit multiply will also have 4 16-bit multiplies, but also must do 64-bit additions, whereas my approach only needs 32-bit additions (and no actual shifts since on a 16-bit processor the 16-bit words of the product will be individual accessible).